# pyspark calculate custom metric on grouped data

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, large-data, pyspark-pandas, pandas-udf

I have a large dataframe (40 billion rows+) which can be grouped by key, I want to apply a custom calculation on few fields of each group and derive a single value for that group. eg, below dataframe has group_key and I want to derive a single value from col1 and col2 for the group_key. This calculation involves complex looping for col1 and col2. I have written a pyspark UDF which works fine and returns me the desired output for each group.
However, the row-by-row UDF runs for few thousand rows which is slow, but it definitely does not run for 40 billion rows.

```
group_key col1 col2
123       a    5
123       a    6
123       b    6
123       cd   3 
123       d    2
123       ab   9
456       d    4  
456       ad   6 
456       ce   7 
456       a    4 
456       s    3
```

desired output

```
group_key output
123       9.2
456       7.3
```

I know pyspark UDF is the worst choice since its row-by-row operation. For vectorized or batch operation I tried using pandas_udf (PandasUDFType: GROUPED_MAP) on each group. If I try to use for loop inside output_calc_udf it throws error. My logic needs to traverse each row of the dataframe passed to the pandas_udf and create a list out of it which I need to traverse few times until I keep pop-ing list elements and the list is empty. Its quite complex. But as I am understanding I cannot really do looping in vectorized operation ? How else I can execute the UDF for 40 billion rows ?

```
schema = StructType([StructField("output", DecimalType(), True)])

@F.pandas_udf(schema, F.PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)

def output_calc_udf(pdf):
    pdf=pdf[['output']]
    return pdf
    
df_prob_new2.groupBy("group_key").apply(output_calc_udf).show(truncate=False)
```

Comment: would it be possible to share a description of the intended operation(s) within outfput_calc_udf?

Comment: @samkart def output_calc_udf(col):
    while len(col) > 0:
        for m in col:
            key = m[0]
            value = m[1]
            if value > val1:
                val1=value  
                val2=key                 
                i_list=col.index(m)         
        if (val2 in t_list):
            del  col[i_list] 
return t_fnl[0] col is a list of lists. I collapsed the rows for a group in one column - list of list. passing it to pyspark UDF. trying to do the same in pandas_udf SCALAR  - getting tricky to pass a array of array to the pandas_udf. Unable toformat code

Comment: I am passing the list of lists field to the UDF. Then until this list is empty I keep traversing the list. Take the max (key, value) from the list items. Then add this max key to another list and also the max value to another list. Then delete the max list (key,value) from the original list. Then again I traverse the list of list and get the max. If the max key already exist in my derived list then delete the list from original list. Finally I have a list of values from which I calculate a metric.

Comment: I am trying pandas_udf SCALAR where I pass the array of array field to the udf. but I am getting error " in verify_result_length
    "expected %d, got %d" % (len(a[0]), len(result)))
RuntimeError: Result vector from pandas_udf was not the required length: expected 10000, got 1". Possibly my pandas series is not right. I am not sure how to represent a array of array as pandas series and then traverse the seriese

Comment: @samkart `df_arr.printSchema()
df_arr.select("key_value_arr").show(truncate=False)
v=pd.Series(df_arr.select("key_value_arr"))
print(v)` root
 |-- user_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- linked_user_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- key_value_arr: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
|key_value_arr |[[AE, 0.99], [CE, 0.99], [A, 0.50], [C, 0.83]]|
0    DataFrame[key_value_arr: array<array<string>>]
dtype: object

Comment: I cannot figure out what is meant by "pandas udf returning pandas series must have the same length of the input and output ". How can the input array length of 12 elements be similar to string length of 3 for the output ?